# django AdminSite instance delete error in model

Tags: python, django

I created an instance of AdminSite as I wanted the admin page for editing the models available under my app (as opposed to the project):

in the myproj/myapp/admins.py I have:

```
from django.contrib.admin.sites import AdminSite
from models import mymodel

class myadminsite(AdminSite):
    pass

my_admin_site = myadminsite(AdminSite)
my_admin_site.register(my model)
```

in the myproj/myapp/urls.py I have :

```
url(r'admin/', include(my_admin_site.urls)),
```

So when I point my browser to 'http://example.com/myapp/admin' I get the admin page correctly and when I log in I see the model also. I am able to add and modify any of the model objects without any problem. BUT when I try to delete any of the model objects it gives me this error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /myapp/admin/myapp/mymodel/2/delete/
u"<class 'django.contrib.admin.sites.AdminSite'>" is not a registered namespace
```

I have been trying for almost four hours now to figure out what is wrong but am unable to. Any ideas/help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you show what the imports in `myproj/myapp/urls.py` look like?

Comment: `from django.conf.urls import patterns, url, include
from admin import my_admin_site
import views`